# Filter data inside array and returns object filtered with group

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an object like this and I need to filter the **rules** within each **group item**, however I need to also return the **group name next to the filtered rule**

```
{
  "id": "rulesCompany",
  "group": [
    {
      "name": "Cadastral",
      "rule": [
        {
          "title": "Receita Federal",
          "description": "Fonte atualizada mensalmente.",
          "homonym": false,
          "criticality": "high"
        },
        {
          "title": "CNAE Primário - Alteração",
          "description": "Fonte atualizada mensalmente.",
          "homonym": false,
          "criticality": "high"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Dados modelados",
      "rule": [
        {
          "title": "Nível de Atividade - Alteração",
          "description": "Fonte atualizada mensalmente.",
          "homonym": false,
          "criticality": "high"
        },
        {
          "title": "Faturamento Presumido",
          "description": "Fonte atualizada mensalmente.",
          "homonym": false,
          "criticality": "medium"
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

[image]

For example, I need to return the group "Cadastral/Receita Federal" if I search for "Rece" in search field, but I don't know how to filter data inside data.

What I've done so far:

*Module.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slide-out :visible.sync="isVisible" :title="text.header">
      <div slot="header">
        <div>
          <button class="neo-bt-icon--big slideout__close--button" @click="isVisible=false">
            <svg><use xlink:href="/red/neo-assets/images/simple-line-icons.svg#arrow-2-left"></use></svg>
          </button>
          <h1 class="slideout__header--text">
            {{ text.header }}
          </h1>
          <div class="neo-form-toggle-list__item neo-form-toggle neo-form-toggle--checkbox">
            <input type="text" class="neo-form-field" placeholder="Buscar" v-model="searchQuery">
            <input class="neo-form-toggle__field" :id="selectAllRules" @click="selectAllRules($event)" type="checkbox"/>
            <label class="neo-form-toggle__label" :for="selectAllRules">selecionar tudo</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div slot="content">
        <div v-for="policyRule in filteredPolicyRules.group" :key="policyRule.name"
          class="neo-form-group">
          <li v-text="policyRule.name"></li>
          <div class="neo-form-toggle-list__item neo-form-toggle neo-form-toggle--checkbox">
            <input class="neo-form-toggle__field" :id="policyRule.name" @click="selectGroupRules(policyRule.rule, policyRule.name, $event)" type="checkbox" v-model="policyRules.name" />
            <label class="neo-form-toggle__label" :for="policyRule.name">selecionar grupo</label>
          </div>
          <div class="neo-form-toggle-list neo-form-toggle-list--inline">
            <div v-for="rule in policyRule.rule" :key="rule.title"
              class="neo-form-toggle-list__item neo-form-toggle neo-form-toggle--checkbox">
              <input class="neo-form-toggle__field" :id="rule.title" :value="rule" name="rule" type="checkbox" v-model="checkedRules"/>
              <label class="neo-form-toggle__label" :for="rule.title">{{ rule.title }}</label>
              <h6 class="neo-text-disabled-options">{{ rule.description }}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div slot="footer">
        <span>{{ checkedRules  }}</span>
      </div>
    </slide-out>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

import SlideOut from '@/components/shared/slideout/SlideOut.vue';

export default {

  name: 'ModulePolicyRules',
  props: [],
  components: {
    SlideOut,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isVisible: false,
      policyRules: [],
      searchQuery: '',
      checkedRules: [],
      filteredRules: [],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredPolicyRules() {
      const me = this;
      if (this.searchQuery) {
        me.filteredRules.pop();
        this.policyRules.group.filter((ruleGroup) => {
          ruleGroup.rule.forEach((rule) => {
            if (rule.title.startsWith(this.searchQuery)) {
              console.log(me.filteredRules);
              me.filteredRules.push(rule);
            }
          });
        });
        console.log(me.filteredRules);
        return me.filteredRules;
        // return this.policyRules.group.filter(item => item.name.startsWith(this.searchQuery));
      }
      return this.policyRules;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    async loadData() {
      const rules = await this.$store.dispatch('policyrules/setPolicyRules');
      this.policyRules = rules;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadData();
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  .neo-form-toggle__label {
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  .neo-text-disabled-options {
    text-transform: none;
  }
</style>
```

**Object expected result** using "Rec" in search field:

```
{
  "name": "Cadastral",
  "rule": [
    {
      "title": "Receita Federal",
      "description": "Fonte atualizada mensalmente.",
      "homonym": false,
      "criticality": "high"
    },
  ]
},
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a sample of the expected output?

Comment: Yes, edit done!

Comment: I don't really get it. You show us what the output should be but how does the unfiltered array actually look like? The one above doesn't has the desired entry in it.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen the objects were different, I made one more edition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this computed prop.

```
filteredPolicyRules() {
  if (this.searchQuery) {
    return this.policyRules.group.reduce((groups, { name, rule }) => {
      const rules = [];

      rule.forEach(r => {
        if (r.title.startsWith(this.searchQuery)) {
          rules.push(r);
        }
      });

      if (rules.length > 0) {
        groups.push({
          name,
          rules
        });
      }

      return groups;
    }, []);
  }

  return this.policyRules;
}
```

I'd suggest calling them `groups` and `rules` (plural) respectively, to avoid future confusion -- after all they are arrays.

#### Full demo:

```js
const policyRules = {
  "id": "rulesCompany",
  "group": [{
    "name": "Cadastral",
    "rule": [{
      "title": "Receita Federal",
      "description": "Fonte atualizada mensalmente.",
      "homonym": false,
      "criticality": "high"
    },
    {
      "title": "CNAE Primário - Alteração",
      "description": "Fonte atualizada mensalmente.",
      "homonym": false,
      "criticality": "high"
    },
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Dados modelados",
    "rule": [{
      "title": "Nível de Atividade - Alteração",
      "description": "Fonte atualizada mensalmente.",
      "homonym": false,
      "criticality": "high"
    },
    {
      "title": "Faturamento Presumido",
      "description": "Fonte atualizada mensalmente.",
      "homonym": false,
      "criticality": "medium"
    }
    ]
  }]
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      searchQuery: '',
      policyRules
    }
  },

  computed: {
    filteredPolicyRules() {
      if (this.searchQuery) {
        return this.policyRules.group.reduce((groups, { name, rule }) => {
          const rules = rule.filter(this.matchFilter);

          if (rules.length > 0) {
            groups.push({
              name,
              rules
            });
          }

          return groups;
        }, []);
      }

      return this.policyRules;
    }
  },

  methods: {
    matchFilter(item) {
      const
        search = this.searchQuery.toLowerCase(),
        term = (item.title || '').toLowerCase();

      return term.includes(search);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="searchQuery" placeholder="Search..." />
  <pre>{{ filteredPolicyRules }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, however I have a problem, when I am cleaning the search field, I need to restore the original object, but it is not happening, what happens is that I stay with the data filtered.

Comment: You know what, I actually missed a `return` keyword. Check out my little edit above and let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) returns you the "reduced" *copy*, so it should not modify the original data. That being said, if you choose to go with my approach, you don't really need this object `filteredRules` anymore.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! I didn't know this concept of reduce, it was of great help.

Answer (score 1):

So first I've put your list into a `map` variable. Then I'm filtering that by checking if any of the wanted properties contain the search term. The `array.filter` Method returns a new array based on what entries returned true and what false.

I'm checking inside name, title and description. Also I made everything lower case so case doesn't matter.

[Array.prototype.filter Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const term = 'CNE';

console.log(map.filter(e => {
  const { name } = e;
  if(contains(name, term)) return true;

  for(const _r of e.rule) {
    const { title, description } = _r;
    if(contains(title, term)) return true;
    if(contains(description, term)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}));

function contains(str, term) {
  return str.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
}
```

And I would also suggest like Yom in his answer that you use `groups` and `rules` so you can name them better. So that then would be `groups.filter(group => {[..]})` and `for(const rule of group.rules)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used your validation to characters!!